# Bootcamp cannot be selected through option key after patitioning using recovery

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, partition

I have installed windows 10 on my Macbook late 2009 unibody and thus far have worked well.
I wanted to increase the capacity of my Bootcamp partition so I used recovery to reduce the size of Macos and allocate that space to windows 10, upon restarting the device I was unable to boot in Bootcamp and macos, Bootcamp does not show up when pressing the option key through resetting pram [[image]
After resetting Pram I am able to boot into Macos but not into bootcamp[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8XHJ.jpg)[image]I was able to boot through macos and see that macos can still detect the Bootcamp partition[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zNmk.jpg)

But by Opening bootcamp through this way it shouwed "No bootable device, insert boot disk and press enter"[image]

Results from diskutil list:

```
Apples-MacBook:~ apple$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                119.8 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data unti                    49.2 GB    disk0s4
   5:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                80.0 GB    disk0s5
```

Results From sudo fdisk /dev/disk0/ :

```
Apples-MacBook:~ apple$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Password:
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30401/255/63 [488397168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  234038808] HFS+        
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 234448448 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
 4: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 235717984 -   96168608] Win95 FAT-32
```

Results from gpt show:

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  234038808      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  234448448    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  235717984   96168608      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  331886592     262144         
  332148736  156248064      5  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  488396800        335         
  488397135         32         Sec GPT table
  488397167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Can you post the output from the commands `diskutil list`, `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`? These command will not change your Mac. The commands just print out partitioning information. If possible, edit your question and add the output.

Comment: Here are the results from the commands, Thank you for the quick response! @DavidAnderson

Comment: I do not think you added space to the partition containing the `BOOTCAMP` volume. The output you posted shows instead that a new partition was created. The volume in this partition appears to have the label `unti`. If I am wrong, then can you explain how you allocated the space to Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, the original space of Bootcamp was 80gb, I plan to use the partitioned space `unti` in Windows by using the Computer management application in Windows 10. I allocated the space to windows 10 by using a modified version of Bootcamp Assistant to Install windows 7 and upgrading to windows 10

Comment: So where is Windows installed now? In the `BOOTCAMP` volume or the `unti` volume?

Comment: it is installed on `Bootcamp` and `unti` is just a blank volume formatted to Fat so that windows 10 could read it

Comment: Windows 10 does not have the ability to add the space from the `unti` volume to the `BOOTCAMP` volume. At least, Windows 10 alone can do what you propose. You can change the size of the `BOOTCAMP` volume, but you can not change where the volume begins.

Comment: You can search the web and find third party tools that can move windows partitions. For example, Winclone. The are also free ones out there. You should backup all your data first. However, if your data is backed up, then why not just reinstall Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message appears when there is no partition flagged as active in the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table. The `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` command prints out the contents of the MBR table. The active partition is indicated by an `*` character. This is absent in your posted output. If the fourth partition contains Windows, then you can use the `fdisk` command to flag the fourth partition as active. If the fifth partition contains windows, then you would need to first put the fifth partition in the MBR. Most users opt to download and use the `gdisk` command do this.

I should warn you that if you fix this problem, there still exists the possibility that Windows may interpret your repartitioning actions as an attempt to illegally clone Windows to a new machine. If this happens, then the easiest solution to this problem would be to rebuild the BCD.

The commands below can be entered to put the fifth partition back in the MBR partition table and make the partition active. Hopefully Windows will boot. You probably will need to enter the commands while booted to OS X Recovery. The `sudo` may not be needed. Note also that the `fdisk` command is interactive.

```
sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk0
e 4
7
n
332148736
156248064 
f 4
q
y
```

If entered correctly, then the MBR partition table should appear as shown below.

```
Apples-MacBook:~ apple$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Password:
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30401/255/63 [488397168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  234038808] HFS+        
 3: AB 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 234448448 -    1269536] Darwin Boot 
*4: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 332148736 -  156248064] HPFS/QNX/AUX
```

If the values in the `cyl`, `hd` or `sec` columns are different, don't worry. These values are no longer used.

Comment: If you feel the answer solved your problem, then you should accept the answer. This will put a green check mark next the my answer. Others will know an answer was found.